# Can't login as admin after upgrading from 11.04 to 11.10

Tags: 11.10, login

All,

I can login using the guest account and i can login using the terminal (Ctrl-Alt-F1).  Every time i try to login graphically it accepts my password and attempts to log in.  Something fails and then the graphical login screen returns.

I have read that executing the following command `sudo rm ~/.Xauthority` is supposed to help.  Unfortunately, this command just returns 'can't find file'.

I really need to get this fixed...my wife needs to use the computer and get to her files.

Another glitch i noticed is that the shutdown always return the login screen instead of shutting down the computer.

Answer (score 2):

Removing `~/.Xauthority` and restarting lightdm didn't work for me either, the file seems to be immediately recreated every time, however I did 2 things, possibly one of which solved my problem with logging in.

1. I had previously added some custom command to the file `/etc/profile`, which I removed.
2. There was another file `~/.xsession-errors` which I removed as well.

After that *and* deleting `~/.Xauthority` I was able to successfully log in, I don't know which of those things caused it though because I did them at the same time.
Hopefully this will be useful to you in solving your logging in problem. One other thing I did was to stop some services I had recently installed, but unless it took a long time to take effect that didn't seem to help either, might be worth a try though.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. This is intriguing; I had exactly the same problem as you, and deleting my .Xauthority file solved it. 
I'm not sure it will make a difference, but while in your home directory could you try running `sudo rm./.Xauthority`? Restarting lightdm using `sudo service lightdm restart` (or restarting your computer) might help too.

If it doesn't, could you post a copy of your /var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log? You might be able to access it using the Log File Viewer, or Nautilus, from your guest account.