# Cannot login graphically after update to 13.04

Tags: xorg, login

I cannot log in to a particular user's account in X after upgrade to 13.04. The password is accepted, the screen goes blank but rather than getting the desktop I am quickly returned to the login screen.

I can log in as that user if I go to a text console using Ctrl+Alt+F1.

I can log in as other users in X.

I have switched to gdm but the results are the same. I have also installed gnome-shell and xfce and but cannot log in to them either.

Where should I look to troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/67702/cant-login-as-admin-after-upgrading-from-11-04-to-11-10

Comment: FIXED. Thanks everyone for the suggestions. The problem was caused by an error in my .profile. Don't know why it did not cause problems before the upgrade. Request moderators to close this question.

Answer (score 2):

I had the very same problem some months ago, but can't quite point to it. Things to try: Go to text console, log in and check:

- file permissions on `/usr/`, `/etc/` and subfolders should mostly be 0755
- add another user account. Can you log in graphically as him? If you can, it's about something in your home:

  - something I solve just by deleting (backup!) `~/.Xsession` or basically `~/.X*`
  - the jackhammer: `mkdir ~/backup && mv ~/.??* ~/backup`. If that doesn't kill it, the problem is not within your account.

Answer (score 1):

In xubuntu if you change the display (only had to do this if I changed the GPU I was using, moved HDD into another system, but I never changed monitors)
delete these files

- `~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-desktop.xml`
- `~/.Xauthority`
- `~/.ICEauthority`

If you have a error in a lightdm script it can cause this
Lightdm scripts are set in this file `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`

They start with these lines: (these are not stock)

- `greeter-setup-script =`
- `session-cleanup-script =`
- `session-setup-script =`
- `display-setup-script =`